# Why is my passed in array into props spread out into it's containing objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### The Context:

I have a webproject set up with React. I have 3 stages in my application:

- A raw view that renders groups (folders with title).
- Each group renders his childs (the images it contains).
- Every image child renders the iamge and some text + tags

The `RoomListView` has the state and passes it down to `RoomListViewGroup`.
This next component then grabs the title from it and maps through the items, creating a `RoomListViewGroupItem` view for each item (Picture with title etc.).

The problem is happening between the first 2 components.

### The Problem:

My state in `RoomListView` looks like this (sample data - hardcoded -no api calls):

```
state = {
folders: [
  {
    title: "Wohnzimmer",
    items: [
      {
        img:
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg",
        title: "Wand links Eingang",
        tags: ["Elektro"],
        folder: "Wohnzimmer"
      },
      {
        img:
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg",
        title: "Wand rechts Eingang",
        tags: ["Wasser"],
        folder: "Wohnzimmer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Küche",
    items: [
      {
        img:
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg",
        title: "Wand links Eingang",
        tags: ["Elektro"],
        folder: "Wohnzimmer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
};
```

I pass my props down from `RoomListView` like this:

```
renderFolders = () => {
return this.state.folders.map((folder, i) => {
  return (
    <RoomListViewGroup key={i} title={folder.title} items={folder.items} />
  );
});
};
```

So the error I get is following:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

So I'm accessing it the passed in props in `RoomListViewGroup` like this:

```
renderDocs = () => {
console.log("this props are: ", this.props);
return this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
  <RoomListViewGroupItem key={i} {...item} />
));
 };
```

This is where the real problem resides. 
The error message basically is saying that this.props.items is no array altough I pass it in from `RoomListView`

I debugged it and console logged it and I don't get this kind of behaviour. 
It ran a few times. 
* Sometimes it's value `this.props.items` is undefined and sometimes it's not an array but the values of the array itself.

[image: Please look at this Screenshot]

Please look at this screenshot and see how the props differ on each run (the first time, it has items in it and it is an array). But then it's "spread" out it seem, altough I never spread it.

**Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are  you loading data from an API or they are static data as you posted here?

Comment: Yep the state is just static for now. Hard coded.

Comment: Ok. can you add the 2 components here full code?

Comment: RoomListViewGroup: https://pastebin.com/cdijkuDj
RoomListView: https://pastebin.com/qZVNcMex

Comment: To me it looks like `<RoomListViewGroupItem key={i} {...item} />` is unwrapping props to `RoomListViewGroup` component itself, instead of passing it to required component. check imports

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke indeed, `import RoomListViewGroupItem from "./RoomListViewGroup";` section shows that you are importing the wrong component

Comment: Oh My Gooosh !! Thank you guys. This was it. Man am I stupid or what haha.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :D